# No module named 'selenium'

Tags: python, selenium

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

[the python version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKDXy.jpg)
[selenium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riv3r.jpg)
pip install selenium ,it reminds me below:
`Requirement already satisfied: selenium in d:\program files\python\lib\site-packages`

and the directory 'd:\program files\python' is python 3.6

it seems that every thing is wright.
win7,python3.6 and put it in path,selenium3.4 and its wright location,pip9.0 with python3.6.

i dont no where i am wrong.

English is not my motherlangue,i am not so good at it,i try to give more wright information and detail .

Comment: Have you installed it?

Comment: selenum?pip install selenium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might be running in a different version of python then your pip is installing.  You can check using pip --version.  For example:

I can check my 3.5 python branch with

> pip --version
>   pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)
>   and from here pip freeze will list the modules installed under the python3 branch...

...versus if I check the 2.7 branch:

> pip2 --version
>   pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
>   I will find a different set of packages installed using pip2 freeze.

If you have selenium installed under one branch and are running your code under another branch, that will cause your mysterious error.  Please comment back if you need more help.  Hope this helps!

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from D:\Program Files\python\lib\site-packages\pip-9.0.1-py3.6.egg (p
thon 3.6)

Comment: python3.6,pip9.0.1,i think they are wright.and i use python3.6.

Comment: If you open an interactive window with python 3.6, can you import selenium there?

Comment: yes ,may be this is what i want to say.interactive,i think it is the same with terminal ,which begain with:>>>,from this place :from selenium imoport webdriver,then:d = webdriver.Chrome(),last:go,and the chrome is started!

Comment: but,from cmd :E:\pyfile\vehicle\add_id.py,it gives me:No module named 'selenium'

Comment: I am not sure but t sounds like a pathing error.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with windows.  Can you post some of your code and i'll try it on linux.

Comment: solve it! not because py2.7 or py3.5,but anaconda.I know little about it,and I thought it is just a tool of python.Now I know it is another version of python.Unstall anaconda,everything is ok.Thanks for  paying attention to this problem  and giving me advices.